# IdUDPClient , how to send a packet to server?

Tags: delphi, indy10, delphi-xe3

How to correctly send a packet to a UDP server? I'm trying but it's not working an I did not received anything from the server.

What I need is to send a packet: `int64|int|int`

And receive a packet back from the server: `int|int|int64`

How to do it correctly? Thanks.

```
type
  Tconnecting = record
    a: int64;
    b: integer;
    c: integer;
  end;
  Treply_connect = record
    a: integer;
    b: integer;
    c: int64;
  end;

var 
  udp: TIdUDPClient;
  send_data: TIdBytes;
  received_data: TIdBytes;
  i: integer;
  packet: Tconnecting;
  reply_packet: Treply_connect;

begin
  packet.a := 41727101980;
  packet.b := 0;
  packet.c := RandomRange(1, 9999999);
  SetLength(send_data, sizeof(packet));
  Move(packet, send_data[0], sizeof(packet));
  udp := TIdUDPClient.Create(nil);
  try
    udp.Host := 'server.com';
    udp.Port := 1234;
    udp.SendBuffer(send_data);
    SetLength(received_data, 0);
    i := udp.ReceiveBuffer(received_data, 5000);
    Memo1.Lines.Add('Data reiceived! Len:'+IntToStr(Length(received_data))+',data:|'+BytesToString(received_data, 0)+'|');
  finally
    FreeAndNil(udp);
  end;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are not using `ReceiveBuffer()` correctly.  You are setting the size of the output buffer to 0 bytes, so `ReceiveBuffer()` will not have any memory to read the received data into.  You need to pre-allocate the output buffer to the max size you are expecting.  The return value of `ReceiveBuffer()` will tell you how many bytes were actually read into the buffer.

In other words, change this:

```
SetLength(received_data, 0);
```

To this:

```
SetLength(received_data, SizeOf(Treply_connect));
```

And change this:

```
Memo1.Lines.Add('Data reiceived! Len:'+IntToStr(Length(received_data))+', data:|'+BytesToString(received_data, 0)+'|');
```

To this:

```
Memo1.Lines.Add('Data received! Len:'+IntToStr(i)+', data:|'+BytesToString(received_data, 0, i)+'|');
```

On a separate note, Indy has a `RawToBytes()` function you can use to copy your packet into a `TIdBytes`:

```
send_data := RawToBytes(packet, SizeOf(packet));
```

And a `BytesToRaw()` function for when you want to extract the received packet:

```
BytesToRaw(received_data, reply_packet, SizeOf(reply_packet));
```